# Gradle build faild: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I create project using android studio 3.0.1 and add firebase to the app.
When I try to build the project, the build faild and got below exception.

Build error
[image: build error]

Gradle build script dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle build project level.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

After adding `multiDexEnabled true` and `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` I got below error

[image]
After running `gradlew build` I got below message.

```
> Configure project :app
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\jem001.TGLCT\AndroidStudioProjects\OkpabackBackend\app\google-services.json


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 32s
20 actionable tasks: 20 executed
```

Please how to fixe it?

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  It's better to copy the text into the issue and format it as a code block, like you did with your second sample.

Comment: can you try and build trough the command line using `./gradlew build` and post the error message

Comment: I edited the question with the result of `gradlew build` command. The build failded. @LordRaydenMK

Comment: The dependencies build okay for me, although I'm using a later version of the Android Plugin for Gradle.  Try cleaning your project and rebuilding.

Comment: Can you please show me your build script? app and project so that I can compare with mine. Thanks @BobSnyder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I recommend you first try cleaning your project and rebuilding.

I am able to build successfully with these scripts:

**Project**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // These are later versions than you have.
        // I'm using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 1.  It requires build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha01
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha01'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App Module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Copied from your post
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thank a lot. After changing classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` to the one your add classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'` it works. @bob-snyder . Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add Multidex library to project gradle

```
   android {
            compileSdkVersion 26
            buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
               minSdkVersion 21 
               targetSdkVersion 26
               multiDexEnabled true
              }
           }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }
```

if you are using unit tests then in application class for base class add below lines into it

```
 public class ApplicationName extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}}
```

After that add this lines into the manifest file

```
 <application
    android:name="com.packageName.ApplicationName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_new"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme1"
    tools:replace="android:icon,theme">
```

Comment: After adding your suggestion I got error. I post the error in the question edited @mahesh-keshvala